# Does Accel World vs. Sword Art Online follow the established gameverse timeline, and how intertwined are the storylines?

Tags: accel-world-vs-sword-art-online

As far as I know, the main Sword Art Online games that were released over the past couple of years all follow an alternate timeline in which the players of SAO were kept in Aincrad after Kirito defeated Heathcliff and had to finish the remaining 25 levels. I would like to know if the new crossover game *Accel World vs. Sword Art Online* follows that timeline and which parts of the storypool of both series it is based on. To break this question down a bit:

- Is AW vs. SAO set in the same timeline of the rest of the gamerverse? If so, can the story stand on it's own or will I miss out if I play AW vs. SAO without having played any of the previous games?
- What parts of the story pool of Sword Art Online and Accel World does the game relate to? Is it rather a standalone that borrows characters and locations from both series? Or does it have a definite standing in the main timelines of either series and/or belong to a story arc of one of them?
- I have watched both seasons of SAO and the one season of Accel World as well as some of the spinoffs and OVAs. I haven't seen Accel World Infinite Burst or SAO Ordinal Scale. I have read the SAO aincrad & fairy dance mangas as well as parts of the Accel World manga and it's spinoff Accel World / dural. Is that a sufficient basis (story-wise) for playing AW vs. SAO, or does the game's story line heavily depend on any specific spinoff or lightnovel that I should read/watch before playing it?

Sorry for the convoluted question, feel free to answer in whatever format you find appropriate. Short answers are also welcome if they answer the core of the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English:
Good morning, sorry if I don't understand completely, I'm Spanish and my English is very bad, so I will use google translator and I will try to make myself understood in the best way fixing some other error of the same.

Answering the main question the answer is simple, yes, the game follows the gameverse created so far, maybe it can cause the impression that it release with a very little difference from SAO: Hollow Realization, but as it has been happening with All the gameverse, Accel World vs. SAO is located after this following a continuity in the history that although it is certain that it isn't obligatory to follow, if it's advisable to know better the characters.

-Yes, it's the same gameverse, you can skip the previous games if you want, the story as such is completely original and separated from the rest.

-Since SAO the game is set in 2026 I think, but the gameverse. From Accel World could be considered that the game is situated more or less where the film was made recently, therefore obviate elements not seen in the anime itself as the existence of Metatron and other situations.

-I think you have enough knowledge of both deliveries to understand the whole argument, although it's true as I said before you will not understand everything, because it goes later than offered by the anime of Accel World, but I personally haven't seen all the content Which they offer and I have understood the whole plot and characters.

I hope you enjoy this adventure, as it has one of the best stories created for SAO video games.

Español:
Buenos días, perdón si no se me llega a entender del todo, soy español y mi inglés es algo malo, por lo que usaré google traductor y trataré de darme a entender de la mejor forma arreglando algún que otro error del mismo.

Respondiendo a la pregunta principal la respuesta es simple, sí, el juego sigue el gameverse creado hasta ahora, quizás pueda causar la impresión de que no ya que ha salido con muy poca diferencia respecto a SAO: Hollow Realization, pero como ha ido sucediendo con todo el gameverse, Accel World vs SAO se situa después de este siguiendo una continuidad en la historia que si bien es cierto que no es obligatorio seguir, si es recomendable para conocer mejor a los personajes.

-Sí, es el mismo gameverse, puedes obviar los anteriores juegos si lo deseas, la historia como tal es completamente original y apartada del resto.

-Desde SAO el juego se situa en 2026, pero del gameverse. Desde Accel World se podría considerar que le juego se situa más o menos por donde la pelicula que se hizo recientemente, por ende obvia elementos no vistos en el propio anime como la existencia de Metatron y demás situaciones.

-Creo que posees suficiente conocimiento de ambas entregas para comprender todo el argumento, si bien es cierto como he dicho antes no entenderás todo, pues va más adelante que lo ofrecido por el anime de Accel World, pero yo personalmente no he visto todo el contenido que ofrecen y he entendido todo el argumento y personajes.

Espero disfrutes esta aventura, pues posee una de las mejores historias creadas para los videojuegos de SAO.